# Redirecting user to login page if not authenticated

Tags: c#, .net, forms-authentication

I am using the simple authentication thing.,,..

Using this in config file....

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".COOKIE" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="480"/>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
   <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
```

The user who is not logged in should be sent back to login.aspx. BUT currently it is not happening. User is able to go to any page. While it is working well in my local but not working on server. What is the thing which I am missing...

Still seeking for the answer......

Comment: Looks about right. If it's working on your machine, try checking the machine.config on the server, maybe it's overriding your settings?

Comment: checked both m/c config files still not able to make out

Comment: What I found is also that whoever tries to get into the application it shows as your is already logged IN, where as logic is written in login button click. Howcome application takes it as user is already logged in?

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things to try:

- remove `<allow users="*"/>`
- close the browser, reopen it, clear all cookies, close the browser, reopen and go to site
- check code in the login page to make sure it's not automatically authenticating the user
- try changing the cookie name...maybe it's being shared somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the config is all right. You might check if the machine.config or the IIS ASP.NET settings are overriding the Web.config you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `FormsAuthentication` module is added to the `httpMdules` collection. You might try to add it your self in your `web.config`, in case it has been removed from `machine.config`. This module is what handles the redirect to what you have specified under `authentication/forms`

Comment: I am not using FormsAuthentication module, I am using this authentication, don't know why it is not working on other side

Comment: per default the *FormsAuthentication* is what will make the redirect when a request has the statuscode of denied and *authentication mode* is set to *forms*

Answer (score 0):

I would deny unauthenticated users by default, only make exceptions for the login page and other resources needed.

**Example:**

```
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

...

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: this is actually the one and the same thing. But even then I tried it and it is not working