# Fetching logged on user name from web application

Tags: c#, .net

IS it possible to get the windows LogOn username of client from web application.
and how does this actually works

`Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")` also not works in this case as I don't want user to authenicate first

While

```
Dim ident As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

this is windows specific which gives the user where the code is?

How should I go with this.

Comment: if you go back to my earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471084/redirecting-user-to-login-page-if-not-authenticated .... I was trying with that. But now I am trying with other workarround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found what I want 
Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name gives the logon user name..